# Convert nanosecond to millisecond not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, milliseconds

I'm trying to get milliseconds from NSCalendarUnit. I was able to get nanosecond, but that has way too many numbers. All I want is 2 numbers. Here is my code:

```
var startDate = NSDate()
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)

let millisecond = Double(dateComponents.nanosecond)/1000000
let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", round(millisecond)
timeLabel.text = "\(strFraction)"
```

`timeLabel` shows 00, which is not what it's supposed to show. How can I get milliseconds to show from NSCalendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me (some XCode7 changes...):

```
var startDate = NSDate()
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Nanosecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

let millisecond = Int(Double(dateComponents.nanosecond)/1000000 + 0.5)
let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", millisecond)
```

Comment: Finally!!! Something that works! The only problem is, it shows 3 numbers. How can I get it to only show 2?

Comment: What do you mean with 3 numbers? Example?

Comment: Sure. Milliseconds range from 0...999 so divide by 10000000 (one digit more) since you seem to output it after the decimal point :-) Maybe you should the cal it decaseconds since its 10*milliseconds or simply fractionSeconds.

Comment: Of course it must be named centiseconds (for 100th) not decaseconds (for 10th) ;-)